# Unable to cast Fragment to SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

why is it i could not cast the Fragment to SupportMapFragment.here is the code

```
 googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
```

here is my activity_main.xml

```
<fragment
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be getSupportFragmentManager(). Make sure that your Activity extends FragmentActivity for ActionBarActivity from the support package.

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity,I already extends FragmentActivity in my MainActivity

Comment: Thank you @Illegal Argument,can i ask is this will run to lower version ?like gingerbread ?